# When did the expression "he gets up my nose" originate?

Tags: etymology

Google fails to locate any etymology source and no dictionary online provides an answer.

Comment: How can we not say it's a minced oath for *up your arse*?

Answer (score 0):

Most examples provided by *[Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/uevy5gy#jppvw5y)* are labelled as British and the earliest dates from 1917:

> The Germans must have known about these orders, for even in the day their transports and troops used to expose themselves as if they were on parade. This sure ***got up our nose***, sitting there day after day, with fine targets in front of us but unable to send over a shell. (A.G. Empey, *Over the Top* 114)

At the time, it seems the Americans were using this expression literally, as in this example I found in *The news scimitar. ([Memphis, Tenn.](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn98069867/1919-07-19/ed-1/seq-7/#date1=1756&index=2&rows=20&words=gets+my+nose+up&searchType=basic&sequence=0&state=&date2=1963&proxtext=%22gets+up+my+nose%22&y=0&x=0&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1))*, which was issued between 1907-1926:

> "Perhaps I could do something to help you," said Uncle Wiggily. "I'm not very good at dusting, because it ***gets up my*** pink, twinkling ***nose*** and makes me think I have the epizootic".

Here is another literal example from 1932:

> "I told you I don't like this snow", retorted Prickly Porky. "I have to brush it off the twigs I eat. ***It gets up my nose***. It gets in my coat. What are you grinning at?"
> (***[Evening star](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045462/1932-01-02/ed-1/seq-11/#date1=1756&index=0&rows=20&words=gets+my+nose+up&searchType=basic&sequence=0&state=&date2=1963&proxtext=%22gets+up+my+nose%22&y=0&x=0&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)***, January 02, 1932)

In 1857, a British soldier, Sir William Francis Patrick Napier, also uses it literally:

> Writing in such a fury hurts my wounds, but really the flies and Sir D. Dundas would make Job angry. Those swarming flies get up my nose, and distract me, owing to my wound: five hundred a day is my average slaughter of them! (*T[he Life and Opinions of General Sir Charles James Napier, G.C.B](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Life_and_Opinions_of_General_Sir_Cha/qyw6AAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0).*)

Also, dictionaries like [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-up-nose) and [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20up%20someone%27s%20nose) label it as BE .

Edit: Thanks to @StuartF, I can include here an earlier example in a slightly different form but similar enough to remain relevant. *[Madame Eulalie’s Rare Plums](https://www.madameulalie.org/annots/pgwbooks/pgwleao1.html)* is a site dedicated to the British writer P.G. Wodehouse. It says:

> The OED cites ***“get it up one’s nose”*** as “chiefly in P. G. Wodehouse” though they cite George Ade (one of Wodehouse’s sources for American slang) first, from [*More Fables*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=oz8qAAAAMAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PA167&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22up%20his%20nose%22&f=false) (1900):
>
> > The quiet School Trustee kind of a Man … is the worst Indian in the World when he does find himself among the Tall Houses and ***gets it Up his Nose***.
>
> The OED definition of the phrase is “to become affected by something, esp. to become angry or infatuated.”

Comment: The OED's first citation is 1951, which is very late. But they have an earlier phrase from 1900 "to get it up one's nose (chiefly in P. G. Wodehouse): to become affected by something; esp. to become angry or infatuated." This seems to tie in with the literal meaning of actually getting something up your nose.

Comment: Grateful for your addition, as I don't have access to the OED. I will add something I found about Wodehouse in my answer.

Comment: Americans were "still using" the phrase literally in the early years of the 20th century?  We use it literally still today and have been using it so for at least two hundred years.

Comment: @TimR Well, Green's offers one quote from 2004: J. McCourt ‘Vilja de Tanquay Exults’ in Queer Street 306: "Just then what some bleedin’ dreary-sof Jerry / Jad to say [...] / Got up / My nose an no mistake."

Comment: That's a figurative use.

Comment: Green’s labels it “(orig. US),” and the cite at 1917 is by an American.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an analogy to small insects flying up someone's nose and irritating them.  So saying that someone gets up your nose could liken them to a nuisance insect.

[Here's](https://www.google.co.kr/books/edition/The_Life_and_Opinions_of_General_Sir_Cha/qyw6AAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22get%20up%20my%20nose%22&pg=PA152&printsec=frontcover) an autobiography from a British general in 1857.  On page 152, he describes his frustration with flies attracted by his wounds flying up his nose.